# How many ordered pairs $(A,B)$, where $A ,B$ are subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, are there if |$A|+|B|=4$?

Tags: combinatorics

How many ordered pairs  $(A,B)$, where  $A , B$  are subsets of  $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, are there if $|A|+|B|=4$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: There are five cases.  Count each separately, then sum.

(a) $|A|=0, |B|=4$

(b) $|A|=1, |B|=3$

(c) $|A|=2, |B|=2$

(d) $|A|=3, |B|=1$

(e) $|A|=4, |B|=0$

Answer (score 3):

It's the same as the number of ordered pairs $(A,B)$ where $A$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $B$ is a subset of $\{6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $|A|+|B|=4$, which is the same as the number of sets $X$ such that $X$ is a subset of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ and $|X|=4$, which is $\binom{10}4=210$.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ordered pairs (A,B) where A and B is the subsets of {1,2,3,4,5} is simply sum(i from 0 to 4)C(5,i)C(5, 4-i) = 210, where "C" is the combination, where we count  len(A) from 0 to 4 and len(B) from 4 to 0 (||=0,||=4,||=1,||=3, ||=2,||=2, ||=3,||=1, ||=4,||=0).